# how to store time as 9:00 AM and start adding minutes into it so that it adds like clock time

Tags: python, datetime

how to store time as 9:00 AM and start adding minutes into it so that it adds like clock time( after 59 minutes, it becomes 10:00 AM and after 4 hrs, it becomes 1 PM) in python

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `datetime.timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse # pip install python-dateutil

time_var = parse('9:00 AM') #returns datetime object
print(time_var).strftime('%I:%M %p')
print(time_var + timedelta(hours=4)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
print(time_var + timedelta(minutes=59)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

`.strftime()` is used for string formatting the datetime objects

Comment: I'm glad I could help!